# mysql: Ignoring INSERT if table and/or field doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an accepted/safe way to ignore an insert statement if either the table or a field in a table doesn't exist?

I'm spending a lot of time trying to filter an array against an 'exclude list' (also an array) and I realized that if the 'exclude list' changes often it could be an maintenance headache.  I'm wondering if it would not be easier to process the entire array, create the desired INSERT/UPDATE queries and if the data isn't required (at this time anyway) just ignore the INSERT/UPDATE query.  In the future, if the previously ignored data was desired going forward then alter the DB instead of rewriting the exclude list...  totally dumb idea??

Clarification the data array we are starting with:

A sample of the array (which comes from third parties and is subject to change) would look like this:

```
{
            "ItemTypeCode": 0,
            "ItemTypeDescription": "Normal",
            "VendorId": "621eb496-d6d1-4860-af9b-ccae97bf4ef8",
            "PurchaseOrderId": "d10991e0-a3b5",
            "FreightDataId": null,
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Model": "ZZEAGLEUPGR",
            "StockModel": "",
            "AltStockModel": "",
            "AltModel": "",
            "CatalogProdId": "723b8e0b",
            "CustomerSpecificPricings": [],
            "GasSteamUtilityGrids": [],
            "HvacUtilityGrids": []
        }]
```

where the end user may not need (at this time anyway) the "FreightDataId" or any of the data in "GasSteamUtilityGrids" sub-array.

Comment: Yes, dumb idea. I'd use some version control system, like e.g. [tag:git] for the PHP code and put the INSERTs into forthcoming tables on a different branch. Then, when the times come, activate that branch (=code).

Comment: @PerlDog - not sure how git applies (and probably my bad for not being clearer) but the array is coming to me as a json and being persisted in MySQL DB.  The json files are multi-dimensional and the 'exclude' list can be at different levels in the json, i.e. the json files are not all structured the same as they originate with different vendors but the same keys are used between the various vendors.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then forget my comment. I misunderstood you.

Comment: What are the UPDATE/INSERT queries you derive from the JSON data you receive? Can you give an example? It would clarify your question.

Comment: Yes - will be a bit though.  Out of the office this AM.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be tempted to go that way.

If you allow users to specify the table names and columns you are already on a dangerous path. I would strongly advise against that. Protection is primordial.

But if this is how you want to proceed, you should in fact not use a black list (exclude list), but a white list (include list). Only the listed tables and columns may be specified by the user for performing database actions. This means that when you add new tables and/or fields, you are safe, even if you forgot to adapt the white list.

Don't try to do without such a list. Protection is much more important than the benefit of not having to maintain such a (white) list.

Comment: I have no issue maintaining a white list for the db, I'm just not sure that it makes since to filter the data at the point where the array is processed.  I have no control over the array (they are provided by third party) - so it seems to make sense that if the entire array is processed (using foreach or similar) then I can focus on what actually needs to be in the db for the end use.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I see. It is a bit hard to imagine the purpose of that array. If you want a deeper opinion on that, you would add some sample contents of such an array, and indicate what you do with it.

Comment: Ah, that doesn't work well in comments (when you use tags). Can you make an addition to your question and put it there?